# Facebook API Campaign Create

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some background...
I'm trying to create a Campaign using the graph.facebook.com API.  When I post, I get an ID back, which I thought would most likely be the Campaign-id, when I do a Get, I am returned a list of ID's...presumably campaigns.

When I go the AdManager page to see all my campaigns there is nothing. I have tried searching Adverts and Adsets, but also nothing.  I now have a list of Id's but no idea what they actually represent.

If I do a GET on one of Ids I was hoping I might get some further information about the object (node), but instead I just get the id back and nothing else.

The AdAccount I am POSTing the campaigns to is a SandBox account, not sure if this makes a difference.
...

Can anyone confirm whether or not the id I am receiving is likely to be the CampaignId?

Is there a special way to see campaign's created for a sandbox account?

Is there a further stage I need to complete to get the Camapigns to show up?

many thanks.

Comment: Needs more information, such as example requests. Also, I thought facebook has pretty good documentation that explains what are the URIs, their parameters and responses.

Comment: The documentation shows you how to create a campaign.  I have done what it says and got back an ID, which it says I would get.  I just cannot see the campaign anywhere and wanted to know if anyone else has tried this before, maybe hit a similar issue and realised that there is a further step that is required or that maybe I have missunderstood something.

Comment: To create the Campaign I posted the following in Postman: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_11111<my account no>/campaigns?access_token=1111<my token>&name=testACampaign2&status=PAUSED&objective=CONVERSIONS